# Editing an image according to desired average color

Tags: algorithm, image, colors

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm that would output colorized/modified image according to source image and desired average color of resulting image as an input.

So let's say that I want an average color to be #ffcc00 - then for any given image I can get a new image that has average color of exactly #ffcc00. I don't mind if the resulting image is heavily modified as long as shapes are recognizable.

How should I approach this?

Comment: Bogofill: keep modifying a random pixel to a random value until the average is achieved? (Hmm, when I think about this, probably divergent.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at your #ffcc00 as three distinct parts. You want to make the red channel average become 255, the green channel average become 204 and the blue channel average become zero.

If your image is unsigned 8-bit, all pixels will be in the range 0..255, i.e. no negative values. So the only way to make the red channel average 255 is if all pixels have red=255. Likewise, the only way to make the blue channel average 0 is if you make the blue component of all pixels zero.

That leaves just the green channel. So you have the existing green channel with some mean value and you want to transform that value to 204, so you effectively want to multiply all the green channel pixels by 204/(current mean). If the new mean is higher than the old mean, some pixels will hit 255 and clip, so you may need to iterate multiplying by a little more till you get what you want. Likewise, if the desired new mean is lower than the existing mean, some pixels may clip at zero and you may need to iterate and multiply by a little less till you get what you want.

Have a look [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46431) for a more scientific answer.